# In React is it possible to add and remove elements dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I am rebuilding a project (a drag and drop website builder ) in React that used to be built with a lot of jQuery.

I need to be able to add and remove elements inside one single parent div but all I can find are methods that people say are "anti patterns" in react. Surely there is a way to have a function that can insert some predefined html into a div and have the functionality to remove it from the DOM too.

Maybe I am not thinking correctly and this needs an entirely different approach. Does anyone know how to do this?

Would using the react-jquery package allow me to SAFELY add and remove elements from the DOM? or is that a bit janky?

Comment: React uses state / props to render, so you update either state / props to add remove..

Comment: Although you _can_ monkey directly with the DOM in a React app via plain JS or jquery, it runs counter to the general purpose and pattern of a React app (since one its primary features is management of the virtual DOM). If you are planning to fully embrace React, you should read up on its approach to state management and specifically how to use the ``useState/useReducer`` hooks or add-on global state management packages like Redux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely add and remove elements in react. You are looking for [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

In JSX with the `&&` operator

```
return (
  {showElement && <div>Hello</div>}
)
```

In JSX with the `ternary` operator

```
return (
  {showA ? <div>This is A</div> : <div>This is not A</div>}
)
```

or you can do the logic outside the return in the body of a `Function Component` for example:

```
    const isLoggedIn = this.state.isLoggedIn;
    let button;
    if (isLoggedIn) {
      button = <LogoutButton onClick={this.handleLogoutClick} />;
    } else {
      button = <LoginButton onClick={this.handleLoginClick} />;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
        {button}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: Fantastic! Once your <Greeting /> component is in the DOM how could you then remove it safely?

Comment: The last example was how to swap out Button. To answer your question, I have to ask what is causing it to be removed? Because I'd remove it via the `&&` operator. In the first code snippet if `showElement` is false it will remove the `div` from the DOM. so `{showGreeting && <Greeting isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />}` will mount it if `showGreeting` is true, and unmount if it is false

Comment: Okay cool. Imagine that a component has been rendered to the DOM that amongst other things has a button inside of it that calls a function that pulls out a sidebar full of editors that can edit that generated components style. I want that sidebar to be able to have the option to remove the component.

Comment: In React that sidebar would likely not live inside the element it's going to remove. But sure, it could remove itself or its parent or another component. You'd have a parent class with a state such as showComponent. A function would be passed down via props to whatever button is removing the component which would set showComponent to false, and remove it.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad at explaining. The sidebar lives inside of the Body as a direct child of the body, it is shown and hidden in css but populated dynamically depending on which dynamically added element it is attempting to edit/remove. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yep you can absolutely do that. You can choose to hide via CSS (I used StyledComponents to help me with that, but now I just use Tailwind) and or to unmount and remount via the methods above. Both work. If this answered your question please mark accepted. Let me know if you have any other questions.